# Listar compartilhamento Linux em outro desktop Linux

Tags: linux, samba

Uso um Ubuntu Desktop 16.04. Tenho um servidor de arquivos na minha rede mas não consigo listar esse servidor no meu Desktop. Esse servidor é um Ubuntu Server.

Simplesmente não aparece nenhum servidor na minha lista de redes. Quando tento mapear via linha de comando, o seguinte erro é apresentado, lembrando que já tenho suporte a cifs instalado:

> **mount error(95): Operation not supported
>   Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)**

Comment: Qual o comando que você está usando?

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio sudo mount -t cifs //3.3.3.199/public /media/sharename --verbose -o user=mario